# Convert date column from varchar to date type when column has null values in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table df with col for date. Date_col is of type `varchar`

```
Date_col
1/30/2010
10/7/2020
NULL 
2/28/2017   and so on
```

Tried

```
alter table df
alter column Date_col date
```

Error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Trying to convert column Date_col to type date. There are also null values in the Date_col column. How to convert column type to `date` from varchar.

Comment: The reason that you get the error is because of `2/29/2017` (2017 is not a leap year). If your dates are correct then the code works: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=bf5152533ad341d124487b8d51665c67

Comment: table does not work even then. Changed the dates now

Comment: Did you check the fiddle link in my previous comment? The code works fine when the dates are correct. So double check your data.

Comment: Then the problem is with your data and/or your settings. Maybe the format of your dates is not consistent like 'm/d/yyyy'.

Comment: Here its all random data. Yes my data has m/d/yyyy as values or m/dd/yyyy (not `d` not `dd` values like 4/3/2020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format to convert your strings to dates is `101` (`mm/dd/yyyy`).

So first try with a `SELECT` statement to convert:

```
select convert(date, Date_col, 101) Date_col from df
```

If you get any errors then the date strings are not correct dates.
If there is no problem then update the table:

```
update df
set Date_col = convert(date, Date_col, 101)
```

and change the data type of the column:

```
alter table df
alter column Date_col date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=9b1fe028a06996cb449d9c7411fe407c).

Answer (score 1):

First update the value and then change the type:

```
update df
    set date_col = try_convert(date, date_col, 101);

alter table df alter column Date_col date;
```

I would recommend that you check the new value before doing the `update`:

```
select date_col
from df
where try_convert(date, date_col, 103) is null and date_col is not null;
```

You can find out if there are any unusual values in the column that you need to take care of.

Comment: @ShailajaGuptaKapoor . . . `101` works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2d62f4f60c2d0d58a7a234ca5fe81c6.

Answer (score 0):

Because the default date format in sql server is ymd, Do:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

alter table df
alter column Date_col date
```